# How to make responsive image aspect ration and height when resizing

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have two columns. One for image and other is text and buttons with fixed height. For a responsive image I set width 100% and height auto . When resize it keep aspect ration but it doesn't match with second column height.

If I set image height to 100%, it is keep same height with second column but not keep aspect ration of image . Any advice please !

PS

> it have no problem in mobile view may be max-width:567px. I need help in pc view..

```css
.btn {
    width: 100px;
}
.explain {
    height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body class="bg-light">

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 p-0">
                <img src="https://www.petittrain-quiberon.com/files/tao/img/demo/background-1.jpg" class="w-100" >
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 bg-dark text-white p-0">
                <div class="py-5 px-3 explain">Lump LumpLump LumpLump LumpLump LumpLump LumpLump LumpLump LumpLump LumpLump LumpLump Lump</div>
                <div class="py-5 px-3">
                    <div class="row m-0">
                        <div class="btn btn-primary col-md-5">Ok</div>
                        <div class="btn btn-secondary col-md-5 offset-md-2">Cancel</div>
                     </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `object-fit` on the img?

Comment: Yes I tried , but it doesn't solve ..

Comment: When you resize, the width of both columns changes. If the width changes but the height stays the same then the aspect ratio changes. `object fit: cover` solves both your problems no?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for inline styles, but this should work as expected. I think you should switch to background image for this purpose. You need to set fixed height for "row", and then you can set "col" 100% height of its parent.

```css
.btn {
    width: 100px;
}
.explain {
    height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body class="bg-light">

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row" style="height: 400px;">
            <div class="col-md-6 p-0" style="height: 100%;">
                <div style="height: 100%; width: auto;background-image: url(https://www.petittrain-quiberon.com/files/tao/img/demo/background-1.jpg);background-size:cover;"> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 bg-dark text-white p-0">
                <div class="py-5 px-3 explain">Lump LumpLump LumpLump LumpLump LumpLump LumpLump LumpLump LumpLump LumpLump LumpLump Lump</div>
                <div class="py-5 px-3">
                    <div class="row m-0">
                        <div class="btn btn-primary col-md-5">Ok</div>
                        <div class="btn btn-secondary col-md-5 offset-md-2">Cancel</div>
                     </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: thank for your answer . but i want aspect ratio ...